# How to load config.properties file in a Seam Application using web.xml context-param

Tags: jboss, seam, web.xml

I have a seam web application in which I have to include a security module for integrated authentication.
I can see that the module isn't based on seam application because it uses a spring-like notation. 
As the module works defining a listener and a properties file in the web.xml I think it should also work in my app.

Problems are: 
I don't have access to the module's sourcecode.
And it fails to load the config.properties file.

The module hopes to load the file through the following configuration. So I place the config.properties at the same path directory as the web.xml.

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>securityLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>config.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I can only assume that at some point some method like getResourceAsStream can't find the file.

I'm using SEAM 2.2.2 and jboss 5 EAP,
I wonder when/how the jboss container solve this context-param at web.xml
and where it assumes the file may be.

Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Try moving the config.properties file into WEB-INF/classes. It will not be accessible from the class loader if it's just in WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the config.properties file into WEB-INF/classes.

It will not be accessible from the class loader if it's just in WEB-INF.